# Spring-boot my service which is autowired is null

Tags: java, spring-boot, autowired

Field in my project is null and I don't have idea why. I don't initalize in project any autowired variable like new BingoGameService(); - so I don't know why I got null.

```
public class MessageReaction extends ListenerAdapter {
@Autowired
BingoGameService bingoGameService; //NULL

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(@Nonnull MessageReceivedEvent event) {

    if(event.getMessage().getContentRaw().equals("!createBingo")) bingoGameService.createBingoGameForUser(event.getAuthor().getIdLong());
```

This is my service class:

```
@Service
public class BingoGameService {
@Autowired
DiscordUserRepo discordUserRepo;
@Autowired
BingoBoardRepo bingoBoardRepo;
@Autowired
GameMechanics gameMechanics;

    public void createBingoGameForUser(Long id) {

if(bingoBoardRepo.findById(1L).isPresent()){
        String[][] officialBingoBoard = bingoBoardRepo.findById(1L).get().getBingoBoard();
        int[][] scoreBoard = gameMechanics.createScoreBoard(3,3);
        DiscordUser discordUserToSave = new DiscordUser();
        BingoGame bingoGame = new BingoGame(discordUserToSave, officialBingoBoard, scoreBoard);
        discordUserToSave.setUserId(id);
        discordUserToSave.setBingoGame(bingoGame);
        discordUserRepo.save(discordUserToSave);
    } 
}
```

Comment: An `@Autowired` field cannot be `null` **if** it is a proper spring managed instance. If it is `null` it isn't properly managed and you are creating an instance of `MessageReaction` yourself outside the scope of Spring. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19896870/why-is-my-spring-autowired-field-null and https://deinum.biz/2020-07-03-Autowired-Field-Null/

Answer (score 0):

you don't need use @Autowired if you create class with constructor.
Add @Component over MessageReaction class

Spring Boot search for annotation like "@Component" "@Service" etc. if you don't include them over class name, it won't know where inject values/classes

```
@Component
public class MessageReaction extends ListenerAdapter {

private FooService fooService;

 public MessageReaction(FooService fooService){
  this.fooService = fooService
 }


}
```

Comment: I tried do it and I still get nullPointer.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the category of layering of your app, you can annotate classes as `@Component, @Service or @Repository`.

I didn't see any annotation for the class `MessageReaction`.  If it is a generic component you have to annotate it with `@Component`.

This annotation helps Spring container to instantiate the instance of your class `MessageReaction`  and autowire the injected dependencies. Since there is no  default constructor for the class `MessageReaction`, you have to annotate the dependency `BingoGameService` with `@Autowired` annotation.

Comment: I added @Component but it didn't change anything, still getting nullpointer.

Comment: Did you clean and rebuild again? Is there any error message during start up ? Can you share that.?

Comment: During clean I got:
[ERROR]     Invalid packaging for parent POM org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:2.2.6.RELEASE, must be "pom" but is "jar" @ org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:2.2.6.RELEASE

I will edit main question and add pom there.

Comment: @Kriszu Do you have sub modules within your  project?

Comment: No, just single module. I had wrong parent in pom. Now clean and rebuild are good, without fails, but nullpointer still appears.

Comment: I am assuming, you annotated the class as @Component.  Is there any other exception or error before NullPointerException? Review the log